# Pair of literal unifiable? Howto, rules?

Tags: logic

Are these pairs of literals unifiable? How do I determine if they are? What are the rules to go?

$p_1([[X,Y]\mid [X\mid Y]],[Y\mid Y])$
$p_1([A\mid B],A)$

If I had to guess my answer would be both yes and no.

Substituting $A$ with $[Y\mid Y]$ would collide with $X,Y$ but maybe no because a single $A$ is not the same as $[A\mid B]$? so this: $[X,Y]\mid [X\mid Y] = [A\mid B]$ and $[Y\mid Y] = A$?

Comment: I hope my edits are the layout you were going for.